# Regex URL with query parameters from unbroken string in .Net 5

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core

I receive encoded binary array which i decode to reveal urls surrounded by unrelated characters:

> \0\0\0\u0001\0\0\0,\0,models.attaches.AttachImage\0\0\0u\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\0\0\u001b@�K����\u0005(��\u0005(��\0\0\u0001vt�\u0004`\0\0\0!\0!models.ImageList\0\0\0\u0005\0\0\0\u0001\0\0\0K\0\0\0*\0\0\0�\0�https://subhost.host.com/img/del-tay-6t1/d71zhsu.jpg?size=75x42&quality=96&sign=124sa\0\0\0\u0001\0\0\0�\0\0\0I\0\0\0�\0�https://subhost.host.com/img/del-tay-6t1/d71zhsu.jpg?size=80x60&quality=120&sign=124sa\0\0\0\u0001\0\0\u0002\\0\0\u0001R\0\0\0�\0�https://subhost.host.com/img/del-tay-6t1/d71zhsu.jpg?size=140x90&quality=128&sign=124sa\0\0\0\u0001\0\0\u0003'\0\0\u0001�\0\0\0�\0�https://subhost.host.com/img/del-tay-6t1/d71zhsu.jpg?size=400x600&quality=256&sign=124sa\0\0\0\u0001\0\0\u0005\0\0\0\u0002�\0\0\0�\0�https://subhost.host.com/img/del-tay-6t1/d71zhsu.jpg?size=16x30&quality=16&sign=124sa\u0002��\0\0\0!\0!models.ImageList\0\0\0\0@\u0002��\0\0\0\u0005��\0\u0005p\0\0\0\u0002\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0012\0\u00128fe364cc35ce4a8407��\u001b�

my goal is to get those URLs with their query parameters as such:

> https://subhost.host.com/img/del-tay-6t1/d71zhsu.jpg?size=80x60&quality=120&sign=124sa

I am using regex expression

```
https?:.*?jpg.*?(?=\\)
```

this works in online testers like http://regexstorm.net/, but in actual C# .Net 5 regex match returns

> [https://subhost.host.com/img/del-tay-6t1/d71zhsu.jpg?size=75x42&quality=96&sign=124sa\0\0\0\u0001\0\0\0�\0\0\0I\0\0\0�\0�https://subhost.host.com/img/del-tay-6t1/d71zhsu.jpg?size=80x60&quality=120&sign=124sa\0\0\0\u0001\0\0\u0002](https://subhost.host.com/img/del-tay-6t1/d71zhsu.jpg?size=75x42&quality=96&sign=124sa%5C0%5C0%5C0%5Cu0001%5C0%5C0%5C0%EF%BF%BD%5C0%5C0%5C0I%5C0%5C0%5C0%EF%BF%BD%5C0%EF%BF%BDhttps://subhost.host.com/img/del-tay-6t1/d71zhsu.jpg?size=80x60&quality=120&sign=124sa%5C0%5C0%5C0%5Cu0001%5C0%5C0%5Cu0002)

and I am not quite sure why

Comment: could you please include the _code_ in question?

Comment: What you posted is mangled text, not some kind of encoding. `�` is the Unicode replacement character, *only* used when reading bytes using the *wrong* encoding.

Comment: Probably has to do with default locales in online compilers and on your system. Try to specify it in your code.

Comment: If what you posted is a byte array, you **can't** use a regex at all. This simply isn't a string. If you know the format, you can read those bytes and extrract the contents. Otherwise you can hack it - it the program that produced this emits a `NUL` (\0) character at the end of a string (like C and C++ programs do) you can try reading all bytes between `h` and the first `NUL`

Comment: Try `https?:.*?jpg\P{Cc}*`

Comment: Hav you had time to try out my suggestion?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's not text. A regex can't work on binary data. The poster tried to treat a byte array as if it was text, assuming the non-text values are some kind of encoding.

Comment: Where did those bytes come from? A file? The output of a method? Is this a raw memory dump? This *not* encoded content

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 's regex worked perfectly, thank you!
I know this is just a binary array, but considering I only need URLs, and those do decode, I though regex was a solution, albeit a bit hacky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the URLs are not only ending with `jpg`, they go all the way till the first control char or end of string.

You can match any char other than a control char with `\P{Cc}` in .NET regex.

Hence, the solution can be

```cs
https?:.*?\.jpg\P{Cc}*
```

Or, if there is a possibility of two URLs glued to each other, you may use

```cs
https?:(?:(?!https?://).)*?\.jpg(?:(?!https?://)\P{Cc})*
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LQvexT/1).

**Details**

- `https?:` - `http:` or `https:`
- `(?:(?!https?://).)*?` - any char other than a line break char, 0 or more times, but as few as possible, that does not start a `https://` or `http://` sequence
- `\.jpg` - a `.jpg` string
- `(?:(?!https?://)\P{Cc})*` - any char but a control char, 0 or more times, but as few as possible, that does not start a `https://` or `http://` sequence.